# JavaFX .jar file is editable even after Build it

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I am creating an application in JavaFX with SceneBuilder. But after built the project, when I open the .jar file in WinRAR, I saw that my application is still editable in Scene Builder because of open FXML file. FXML file is not encoded and can easily accessible in Java SceneBuilder.

How can I protect my project FXML and CSS file?

Here is the screenshot of my project and the fxml file that is accessible after built.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obfuscating JavaFX application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344768/obfuscating-javafx-application)

Comment: My question is different.
In the link you have given above, he asked about connectivity of FXML file after obfuscating JavaFX files.

My question is, FXML file is editable after obfuscating. Obfuscate is only obfuscate .java files and classes, not fxml file.

Answer (score 0):

This is completly normal.
What you could do is crypting your .fxml file and decrypt it at runtime.
Another solution would be obfuscating your compiled .jar.

For the last solution, take a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/obfuscate-your-javafx).